# How to show in Developer Tools all elements observed by Intersection Observer API

Tags: javascript, developer-tools, intersection-observer

Is there any option to show all active DOM elements still observed by Intersection Observer API in Chromium-based Developer Tools?

I couldn't find it in all of the developer's tools panel and in the Run>Command as well.